# Text input is not styling in CSS

Tags: html, css, input

I´ve trying to use .input{} to style the input in my code, but it is not working.

I would like to make the input element less ugly, maybe even the button submit too.

Also, I was trying to put the code itself here but maybe I don´t know how to ident it properly :(

```
<input type="text" id="login"/>
```

Comment: Simply use `input{..}`

Comment: 'input' elements are hard (and sometimes impossible) to style. The general way to get around this is to hide the input (input type=hidden) and use a `LABEL` or another element around it. W3Schools had an example that I used of square and circle toggle switches using a `LABEL` and a hidden Input.

Comment: For better practice use id's and class because you could have many inputs or any other element repeated more than onces

Comment: "*I was trying to put the code itself here but maybe I don´t know how to ident [sic] it properly*": See [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). It's fine not knowing how to format; as long as your question is comprehensible we can help you with the formatting.

Comment: `.input { ... }` this effects page elements with the attribute `... class='input' ...` . `#input { ... }` This effects things with the attribute `...id='input'...`, and `input { ... }` will effect elements on the page of the type `<input>`.

Answer (score 0):

The input doesn't have a class of "input" so for this case you wouldn't put the "." in front of it. Here's a few ways of writing it out depending on how you want to target it:

`input{styling: here;}`
`input[type = "text"]{styling: here;}`
`input#login{styling: here;}`

I hope you find this helpful